# How previous_refresh_token column in Doorkeeper gem works?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, doorkeeper

```
  # If there is a previous_refresh_token column,
  # refresh tokens will be revoked after a related access token is used.
  # If there is no previous_refresh_token column,
  # previous tokens are revoked as soon as a new access token is created.
  # Comment out this line if you'd rather have refresh tokens
  # instantly revoked.
  t.string   :previous_refresh_token, null: false, default: ""
```

Could someone explain me this part how it works in practice? `If there is a previous_refresh_token column, refresh tokens will be revoked after a related access token is used.` Because with that feature enabled we noticed that refresh tokens are never revoked.